# Why my Table header disappears while filtering the Table data?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search

HTML and JavaScript

```js
$("#btn10").click(function() {
    $(".search-boxes").toggle()
  }),

  $("#comfilter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#communication_mode_table tr").each(function(index) {
      if (index !== 1) {
        $row = $(this);
        var id = $row.find("td:first").text().toLowerCase();
        if (id.indexOf(value) == -1) {
          $row.hide();
        } else {
          $row.show();
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn10"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Filter</button>

<table id="communication_mode_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nature Of Fault</th>
      <th>Push Notification&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' name='all_push' id='all_push' class='all_push' </th>
        <th>SMS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='checkbox' name='all_sms' id='all_sms' class='all_sms' />
        </th>
        <th>Call&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='checkbox' name='all_call' id='all_call' class='all_call' />
        </th>
        <th>Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='checkbox' name='all_email' id='all_email' class='all_email' />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="search-boxes " style="display: none;">
      <th>
        <input id="comfilter" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
```

Why my table header disappears while keying the search box ?

Also  if I put

`if(index !== 0)` , the search box itself disappears from the screen, Can anyone help me to find the solution ?

Is there Any alternative solution available to achieve this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you filter all rows, when you clearly want to filter only rows in `tbody`. You will need to adjust the selector you use and then you will not need `index` criteria either.

```js
$("#btn10").click(function() {
    $(".search-boxes").toggle()
  }),

  $("#comfilter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#communication_mode_table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
        $row = $(this);
        var id = $row.find("td:first").text().toLowerCase();
        if (id.indexOf(value) == -1) {
          $row.hide();
        } else {
          $row.show();
        }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn10"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Filter</button>

<table id="communication_mode_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nature Of Fault</th>
      <th>Push Notification&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' name='all_push' id='all_push' class='all_push' </th>
        <th>SMS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='checkbox' name='all_sms' id='all_sms' class='all_sms' />
        </th>
        <th>Call&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='checkbox' name='all_call' id='all_call' class='all_call' />
        </th>
        <th>Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='checkbox' name='all_email' id='all_email' class='all_email' />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="search-boxes " style="display: none;">
      <th>
        <input id="comfilter" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr><td>12</td><td>34</td><td>56</td><td>78</td><td>90</td></tr>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seem that your code is wrong.

your table body is empty and you perform seach on your
header. so try to reorganise your code, put your id value #communication_mode_table to the table body tag content rather than your
header.